# What is the easiest way to animate a rectangle moving across the screen in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I need a super simple animation where on click, a rectangle will move from one side of the canvas to the other. What is the simplest way to do this?

```
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "600" height = "300" style = "background-color:red">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Comment: Look at [p5.js](https://p5js.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate most of the style properties. On clicking the rectangle you can toggle a class that sets the left property to 100% (- 5% for the width of the rectangle ). clicking it once adds the active class and sets it off on a journey to the right - clicking the active rectangle removes the active class and returns it back to the left.

It is alwatys better to a class with styling than to style the element in the JS itself.

Thank you to @Andrei ShadowS for the skeleton of the code snippet that I then modified.

```js
const rectangle = document.querySelector('.rectangle');

rectangle.addEventListener('click', toggleActive);

function toggleActive() {
    rectangle.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
.rectangle {
    background-color: black;
    width: 5%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition-duration: 4s;
    transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out
}


.rectangle.active {
    left: calc(100vw - 5%);
    transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<p>Click the rectangle to see it move to the right - click it again to more it back to the left.</p>
<hr/>

<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by using a div and JavaScript. Bellow, you can find a working animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Basic Animaiton</title>

    <style>
        .square {
            background-color: black;
            width: 5%;
            height: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            transition-duration: 4s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="square"></div>

    <script>
        //Here your get your element from HTML
        let square = document.querySelector('.square');

        //When you click on the square, the animate funtion runs .
        square.addEventListener('click', animate);


        function animate() {
            square.style.left = "95%";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```